# The constructor StarBitmap(Bitmap, boolean, int)is not visible

Tags: android, printing, stario-sdk

Anyone knows how to fix this error?  The constructor StarBitmap(Bitmap, boolean, int)is not visible. it happens on the second line of this code:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.euro_cert_black);
        StarBitmap starbitmap = new StarBitmap(bm, false, 408);
```

I have no clue how to fix this. 
I checked if there is an import of StarBitmap and there is.
Tried changing it to getResource() from some answers i found but still nothing.
I tried adding public to StarBitmap constructor and still nothing.

The class i have this code in is `public class Print{}`

and the StarBitmap and consctuctor is something like this:

```
public class StarBitmap
{
    int[] pixels;
    int height;
    int width;
    boolean dithering;
    byte[] imageData;

    public StarBitmap(Bitmap picture, boolean supportDithering, int maxWidth)
    {
        if(picture.getWidth() > maxWidth)
        {
            ScallImage(picture, maxWidth);
        }
        else
        {
            height = picture.getHeight();
            width = picture.getWidth();
            pixels = new int[height * width];
            for(int y=0;y < height; y++)
            {
                for(int x=0;x<width; x++)
                {
                    pixels[PixelIndex(x,y)] = picture.getPixel(x, y);
                }
            }
            //picture.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        }

        dithering = supportDithering;
        imageData = null;
    }
```

The StarBitmap by the way is from an sdk of Star Micronics portable printers

Comment: Add `public` before the `StarBitmap` constructor

Comment: I tried that. Still nothing. The StarBitmap by the way is from an sdk of Star Micronics portable printers

Comment: Now please add that public to your posted code.

Comment: I did. But still this doesnt fix my issue

Comment: Actually it was working. The project needed a clean-.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used the default visibility for the constructor starBitmap(). The default visibility enables the accessibility within the same package. But if you want to access the members across various packages it should be public. Refer the link for more info [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Comment: You mean to add public to the StarBitmap constructor?

Comment: Yes, and make the starBitmap as a separate java file.

Comment: It was working when i tried that actually. The project just needed a clean-.-